# Moving from PyQt to PySide using named slots

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside, maya

I'm moving some of our scripts over from PyQt to PySide and had a question regarding slot names. For context, our UI is created with Qt Designer. Saved as `.ui` files. Converted to `.py` files using `pyside-uic`. These scripts are then used inside of Autodesk Maya.

The generated `.py` script connects signals to slots using the command: 
`QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)`.

This looks for slots named `on_<objectname>_<signalname>()` such as `on_pushButton_clicked()`.

Previously with PyQt4, we named our slots as follows:

```
@QtCore.pyqtSlot( name = "on_pushButton_clicked" )
def testButton_pressed( self ):
    print "pressed button"
```

In PySide, this becomes:

```
@QtCore.Slot( name = "on_pushButton_clicked" )
def testButton_pressed( self ):
    print "pressed button"
```

This worked with PyQt, but not with PySide. PySide does not recognise the "name" parameter in the slot anymore. The workaround is to rename `testButton_pressed()` function to `on_pushButton_clicked()`, but I would prefer to not have to do this for all my scripts. Is there a better way to get PySide to recognise the slot "name" argument?

Answer (score 0):

This is clearly a bug. The [PySide documentation](https://qt-project.org/wiki/Signals_and_Slots_in_PySide) says the `name` argument is supported, but it produces a `RuntimeError` (using version 1.2.1) when the signal fires. Without the `name` argument, the signal works normally.

The mechanism for connecting slots by name is definitely still there, because deliberately using an invalid name, e.g.:

```
    @QtCore.Slot(name='on_button_clickedXXX')
    def foo(self):
        print('on_button_clicked')
```

produces this error:

```
    QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName: No matching signal for on_button_clickedXXX()
```

Answer (score 0):

Do like this:

```
@QtCore.Slot(str) 
def on_pushButton_clicked(self, name = "on_pushButton_clicked"):
    print "pressed button"
```

Comment: That did not work for me. I require the function name to be different from the "name" attribute.

ex. def buttonClicked(self, name = "on_pushButton_clicked"):